# What is the correct way to write the abbreviation of "the first"?

Tags: superscripts

I want to write 1<sup>st</sup>. What is the correct way to do so?

- `1\textsuperscript{st}`
- `\mbox{1\textsuperscript{st}}`
- `\mbox{1$^\text{st}$}`
- `$1^\text{st}$`